# How do you model a Java for each loop on a UML sequence diagram?

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

```
for (Item i : collection) {
i.foo();
}
```

In some abstract sequence diagrams you have a *loop* combined fragment with a condition along the lines of e.g. *[for each item]*.

On a sequence diagram featuring Java implementation; what would you use as a loop guard?

If all lifelines must represent an object instance, how would you show that *i: Item* is not a single instance, but on each iteration a different object from the *collection*?

Answer (score 7):

You don't show each single bit in a SD but just an overview: it's an abstraction.

[image]

This quite clearly shows the intention of your loop.

You would show different `Item` instances only if you want to show different behavior during the loop.

Answer (score 4):

For the second part of your question, there is a notation to draw multiple instances in the same lifeline using stacked boxes, for example:

[image: UML sequence diagram loop with multiple instances]

from [A Quick Introduction to UML Sequence Diagrams](http://www.tracemodeler.com/articles/a_quick_introduction_to_uml_sequence_diagrams/)

The stacked boxes used for the `figures` variable indicate it refers to multiple instances, which can be interpreted as being a different instance around the loop. (As usual with UML, the semantics a somewhat in the eye of the beholder)

P. 571 of the UML 2.5 spec states:

> The Lifeline head has a shape that is based on the classifier for the part that this lifeline represents. Often the head is a
>   white rectangle containing the name.

The word "Often" can be interpreted as "take what is needed" as it does not obtrude the use of a single specific form.

Comment: Ah, from the Internet. That must be right :-/ The official UML 2.5 spec does not have that notation. See pp. 593.

Comment: @ThomasKilian true - it was explicit in UML 1 that the lifeline started with an object symbol, and that is the notation for a multi-object symbol which can be used whenever the object has a multiplicity greater than 1. In UML2.5 the wording has changed to 'The Lifeline head has a shape that is based on the classifier for the part that this lifeline represents' and the metamodel has the type of what the lifeline represents as ConnectableElement, which represents a set. So it both a common notation from UML1 and within the allowed notations of the specification of UML 2.

Comment: I took the freedom to add the reference.

Comment: In my opinion, the word "often" means, that most Classifiers have a rectangle notation. None have this stacked boxes notation. Therefore it is also not available for Lifelines. Of course it would be possible to define it in a user defined profile. Whatsoever, it will always represent only one instance, which could be an instance of a collection.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer the spec does not restrict what notation is used - you can use a picture of a kitten if you like and it will still be valid UML.

Comment: @Pete. As I said, it is possible to define it in a user defined profile. You would have to define a stereotype with an image of a kitten, apply this to a Class, let a Lifeline represent it and choose to display the stereotype image instead of the Classifier rectangle. There is no other way to change the appearance of Lifelines or Classifiers in the specification, even though most tools are more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it cannot be done. The loop operator has a `guard` condition and a number of iterations between `minint` and `maxint`. I think, this doesn't allow "for each loop" semantics. If you want to add this, it must be done with a user defined stereotype `«for each loop»`:
[image: stereotype for <code>for each loop</code>s]
An example usage is:
[image: example usage]

Please note that the note symbol is a not a `comment`, but the notation for the stereotype properties. They reference the property `e` of `Client1` and `i` of the Interaction `Example1` (see diagram below). The i-Property is represented by a Lifeline and will refer to a different object in each occurrence of the loop content. This is achieved here by the user defined semantics of my `«for each loop»`.
[image: Class diagram]

As an alternative you could add a semantic free `comment` with the same content. Misusing the `guard` for this purpose is not recommended.

If you want to use a java like iterator the diagram could look like this:
[image: solution with iterator]

This diagram also shows, how to refer to different objects over time: The return value of a `reply` message is assigned to a `Property` of the Interaction or of the Class represented by the Lifeline or a `Parameter`.