# In a sequence diagram, can you make up names of functions that you plan to implement in the future?

Tags: java, uml, sequence, diagram

I have created a method getName() that doesn't exist in the class diagram.

This concept is new to me, and I am not confident in it at all.

Could I please get some constructive feedback for my attempt?

Also, would I have to specify how the students closest companion is calculated and explain how the report is generated by getting student name, coordinates and details of closest companion?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes. The UML is also used to design the application which will be implemented, so in design phase using UML the application's layers, domain objects, services, daos... are detailed. If there are both sequence/class diagrams used then would be safer if the methods used in sequence diagrams are also detailed in class diagrams too

Comment: Thanks Valentin, any chance you could let me know if I'm on the right track with my implementation? Thanks

Comment: In a Sequence Diagram, you just model the process flow of method calls for the objects involved. There is no need to show *how* the methods are implemented and not all the methods of the objects have to appear there. The Class Diagram shows the architecture of your program, that is the classes, how they are related to each other and maybe how they are organized in packages. **Methods appearing in the Sequence Diagram must be in the corresponding Class Diagram**, otherwise you should provide a UML-note telling the viewer of the Sequence Diagram that this method is missing in the Class Diagram.

Comment: It looks fine to me, I would do couple of things differently (1) in the class diagrams there are 3 sections class name, fields and methods, so instead of describing the responsibilities I would list the methods which will be responsible for what is described (2) in the sequence diagram I would use only methods which are described in the class diagrams

Answer (score 0):

Sequence Diagrams show messages. They may refer to operations their target offers or signals their target can receive. This is optional though and it is quite common to first write message names, that later become operations and signals.

I have some remarks about the diagram

- The messages to the controller are shown as asynchroneous calls. Is that on purpose?
- "for all points" is a strange guard condition. You probably want a [for each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54638391/9430250). Just move "for all points" to a comment symbol, because this is the correct place for such a remark.
- the return values must be preceeded with a colon.
- you have two return values (x,y). Only one is possible. Also x and y are attributes of Point, they are not the Point Object. Just leave this empty.
- you don't need to specify 100%. It just depends on the purpose of your diagram. Of course it could be interesting to show, how the report is created.
- the SMTP-Sender can't be a stereotype. You can *apply* a Stereotype to it, for example to give it additional modeling rules. An example would be, that a Class with Stereotype «sender» applied, must have an operation named `send`.
- you are directing the last message to `SMTP-Sender`, but it is defined only for the `Controller`.
- A Class named "Point" should not be responsible for representing a student.